# What is the use of creating texture having width and height equal to Zero?

Tags: opengl, textures

If Opengl allows to create a texture of width = height = 0 then what is the use of specifying other parameters like Internal Format, Format etc. Secondly what is the use of such texture.

Comment: no usage came to my mind, if you have such a case, post it...

Comment: I can't think of a case where this would be useful. Maybe when texture borders were still supported, a 0 size texture would have allowed you to just let it sample the border color if you had no texture data?

Answer (score 7):

#### To understand why you would want this, recall that textures have multiple LODs.

By default you effectively have **1000** images with **0** width and **0** height per-texture because of the default Min/Max LOD. That is actually fine, as long as you do not try to apply a mipmap minification filter. Newer versions of GL will refer to a situation where some but not all LODs are allocated as *mipmap incomplete* rather than calling the entire texture incomplete.

If you look at [`glTexStorage2D (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml) you will notice that it is not possible to create a texture with **0** width, **0** height or **0** LODs because it has to create storage for a ***complete*** texture.

You can create mipmap incomplete textures using `glTexImage2D (...)` if you want and in fact you usually do if you do not set the LOD parameters correctly. Likewise, sizing a texture LOD to **0x0** will effectively free its memory. This allows you to delete your mipmaps without having to re-allocate and send the base LOD to GL.

Whether you find that useful is another matter, but this is something that `glTexStorage2D (...)` cannot do.

Comment: So if texture with 0x0 does not have memory allocated then are the details like  Internal Format, Format etc saved for it?

Comment: @abhijitjagdale: Well, first of all the second format in a call like `glTexImage2D (...)` is not saved anywhere. That is used by GL when it transfers pixel data, it will do format/type conversion as necessary (assuming you pass non-NULL data). Really if you specify a texture image with dimensions: 0x0 the only thing that happens is parameter validation. The set of passed parameters must be compatible even though nothing actually happens.